# Modern IRC client?

Tags: irc

I've been looking all around the web for a good IRC client. Sure, there are some out there, but they all look terrible in terms of design. Being a designer myself, I like having applications that deliver eye-candy.

Things I've tried, which I hated the design for:

- MIRC
- X-CHAT

Design elements that I love:

- Microsoft's Metro interface
- Microsoft Office Ribbon interface (as seen in Office 2007 or later)
- WPF-based applications that deliver great looks

Do you have any suggestions?

While this may be interpreted as a subjective matter, I believe it's not. I'd like an IRC client with some of the design elements above that I like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only WPF based irc client i know of is [floe](http://floe.codeplex.com/). I'd say though, IRC clients looking dated, are a reflection of the fact that its a simple, old protocol, and over time, those design elements have become standard cause they work.

I'd also suggest taking a look at this discussion thread on deviantart - one of the users is working on a [metro style client](http://clindhartsen.deviantart.com/art/MetroIRC-UI-Elements-175875453)

I've tested floe and it wasn't bad. The other one, no. I personally stick to xchat with a custom (black) gtk theme myself.